# Express in the form of $a+ib$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Express 
>   $$\sqrt {\dfrac {1+i}{1-i}}$$
>   in the form of $a+ib$.

My Attempt:
$$\sqrt {\dfrac {1+i}{1-i}}
=\sqrt {\dfrac {1+i}{1-i} \times \dfrac {1+i}{1+i}}=\sqrt {i}.$$

Comment: @quanticbolt, expand $(1+i)^2$ and simplify..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac {1+i}{1-i}=\frac {(1+i)(1+i)}{(1-i)(1+i)}=\frac {(1+i)^2}{1-i+i-i^2}=\frac {(1+i)^2}{2}\quad\left(=\frac {1+2i+i^2}{2}=i\right).$$ 
(the further simplification to $i$ does not help you here).
Hence the TWO square roots are
$$\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\quad \text{and}\quad -\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

Comment: To be fair, those are the two square roots of $i.$ The main error in the OP's attempt is that $\sqrt{i}$ is not in the form $a+ib.$

Comment: Thanks, my fault!

Answer (score 1):

$$i = \exp\left(2\pi n + \frac{\pi}2 \right)$$

$$i^\frac12 = \exp\left(\pi n + \frac{\pi}4 \right)=\cos\left(\pi n+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+i\sin\left(\pi n +\frac{\pi}{4} \right)$$